# CVPixelBuffer to CGImage with Scale Down

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage, ciimage

I have following code to convert `CVPixelBuffer` to `CGImage` and it is working properly:

```swift
let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
// Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))

// Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)

// Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
// Get the pixel buffer width and height
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)

// Create a device-dependent RGB color space
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

// Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
let bitmap = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue|CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
let contextBM = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmap.rawValue)
// Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
let quartzImage = contextBM!.makeImage()

//Unlock the pixel buffer
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))

self.myCGImage = quartzImage
```

Now, I want the `CGImage` that gets created to be smaller in dimensions.  Maybe half the size? Is it possible to modify the above code without running anything extra?

Comment: What does "without running anything extra" mean???

Comment: @matt without an additional conversion.  If I change the width and height, would it just change overall size?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an additional conversion". You're not going to get a different size by magic. You have to size down the CGImage, yourself.

Comment: You are misunderstood of what I am trying to say.  For example, I know you can go `CVPixelBuffer` -> `CIImage` -> `CGAffaineTransform` -> `CGImage`.  This introduces an additional conversion in the middle in to CIImage.

Comment: I don't think I've misunderstood. If you know how to size down a CGImage, then do it. If you don't know, then ask. But do not say "without running anything extra"; obviously you will have to add some code to what you have already.